# how to access External Directory in Jboss 5.1

Tags: java, jboss

I want to access files from External Directory in Jboss 5.1

Currently I have path /home/srvrutil in which all .csv file are present.

my jboss is under /opt/msd/jboss/server/all/deploy/myapp.war

I am showing a list of csv in jsp(myapp.war) file while showing the csv file i am giving a hyperlink to open the csv file.

While opening the file i want to open from /home/srvrutil.

So i tried to add in server.xml

but its not working.

Can any one please help me .

Comment: So i tried to add in server.xml     <Context path="/srvrutil"
                  docBase="/home/srvrutil"
                  allowLinking="true">
         </Context>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  Configure JBoss to follow symbolic links 
        Go to <> /server/all/deploy/jbossweb.sar/content.xml Add allowLinking="true" as:

2 ) Create symbolic link as 
        ln -s /home/cnmsftp/srvrutil/backup /opt/ems/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/all/deploy/ROOT.war/srvrutil

and restart the jboss server and try to access the file.

I tested this solution and found its working fine.